# How to monitor ArangoDB with Newrelic

Tags: arangodb, newrelic, application-monitoring

We’re having Newrelic application monitoring in many projects integrating with classical relational databases and mongo and recently started a new project with the ArangoDB as a multi-model graph database.

I cannot find any article on the web having both ArangoDB and Newrelic creatures in the topic.

Did anyone try to monitor a backend application with ArangoDB using Newrelic? Is it possible? Is it difficult?

If anybody knows, please share knowledge, describe available strategies and possible tactics.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: You can use the `GET /_admin/metrics/v2` HTTP endpoint to obtain server metrics in Prometheus format: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/http/monitoring/#metrics

---

We have a cookbook, that is meant for integration and monitoring of ArangoDB instances using Prometheus and Grafana.

https://github.com/arangodb/docs/blob/147aa14a98c32b238ec21cb06ac740212aa78490/3.7/monitoring-collectd.md

There are to ways you could go about this. If you have some experience with Newrelic and feel motivated to adopt the above cookbook to Newrelic, we would not hinder you and help wherever we can.

Or you would go to our github repositpry and file a feature request after having stared us :) there.

In either case, you'd be awesome.

Comment: _I gave a star for the ArangoDB project in the first week of trial_ ;-)
Recently I got curious about Newrelic’s Java agent overhead and after evaluating it using VisualVM for a Kotlin project I found out numbers to be so horrible that I am no longer interested in using it for JVM (and I consider to rip it off from other projects.)
Seems like your cookbooks are a better alternative. Will evaluate before a final decision.